# Functional Inequality question where $\int^x_0\frac1{f'(t)}dt = \int^x_02f(t)dt $ ,$ 0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(0) = 0$

Tags: functions, inequality, integration

$$\int^x_0\frac1{f'(t)}dt = \int^x_02f(t)dt \tag{1}$$ where  $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(0) = 0$

I need to prove that $$f(\frac1{\sqrt{2}})> \frac1{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$f(\tan (x))> \tan(x) > x , x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})  $$
$$f(e^{-x^2})\geq e^{-x^2}$$

The problem is that i dont know how to derive the function it self.

All I could do was say that $$\frac{d\left(\int^x_0\frac1{f~'(t)}dt)\right )}{dx} = \frac1{f~'(x)}$$

and $$\frac{d\left(\int^x_02f(t)dt\right )}{dx} =2f(x)$$

Comment: I was wondering: assume that $\int_0^x g(t)\, dt=0$ for every $x \geq 0$. Can we deduce anything about $g$?

Comment: There is no *functional inequality* here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get

$$\frac{1}{f'(x)}=2f(x) $$

Thus

$$2f'(x)f(x)=1 \,.$$
or

$$\left( f(x)^2 \right)' =1 \,.$$

Integrate, find the constant and you are done.

Comment: but differentiating two equal integrals doesn't necessarily make them equal right ?

Comment: If two functions are equal, their derivatives are also equal ;)

Comment: Well if two functions are equal, they are the SAME function...

Comment: How is the derivative of a function defined, @The-Ever-Kid?  It is defined in turns of the values of the function.  If two functions are equal at all points, then of course their derivatives are equal.

Comment: The converse is not true, of course - if two functions have the same derivative, they are not necessarily equal.  That might be what is confusing you?

Comment: Thanks this is what confused me coz i remembered my teacher saying somthing like diffrentiating inequalities doesnt always satisfy it though integration does and thought that it applies to equalities to.....silly me :p